# When converting JSON to XML, how to create attributes rather than new elements?

Tags: json

I am new to JSON. I have a program to generate XML from a JSON object:

```
String json_data = "{\"student\":{\"name\":\"Neeraj Mishra\", 
\"age\":\"0012322\"}}";
org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(json_data);   
//converting json to xml
String xml_data = XML.toString(obj);
System.out.println(xml_data);
```

I get this output:

```
<student><name>Neeraj Mishra</name><age>0012322</age></student>
```

But I need this type of input:

```
<student name='Neeraj Mishra' age='0012322'></student>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are passing as a JSON string seems to be an object array of "student". If you wish to get the desired result, try:

```
String json_data = "{\"student\": {\"-name\": \"Neeraj Mishra\",\"-age\":\"0012322\"}}"
```

Output:

```
<student name='Neeraj Mishra' age='0012322'>
```

**EDIT:**
You actually want to use "name" and "age" as a property/attribute rather than an element. This should get the desired result. However, there are no rules about when to use attributes or when to use elements in XML.

Comment: Sorry output is not coming correct Format.Format is <student><student name>Neeraj Mishra</student name><age>0012322</age></student>

Comment: Sorry output is not coming correct Format.Format is                 <student><student name>Neeraj Mishra</student name><age>0012322</age></student> .But I need <student name='Neeraj Mishra' age='0012322'></student>

Comment: Are you still getting the same output even after making the necessary changes in the json_data(which I edited)?? @ganeshkumar

Comment: Still its coming <student name>Neeraj Mishra</student name><age>0012322</age>

Comment: I got solution input is                                                                         
 String json_data = "{\"student\":{\"@name\":\"Neeraj Mishra\", \"@age\":\"0012322\"}}"; Thank u for yur response